# JDK 11 compliant NCSO jar

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, corba

We are using NCSO.jar to interact with Lotus Domino. This internally has dependencies on org.omg.CORBA.* .

We are in the process of migrating to JDK 11 and this version of java do not have these required dependencies due to: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320

I tried searching a lot, but haven't got any leads on whether there is an updated NCSO.jar that is compliant with JDK 11.

I am aware of adding 3rd party glassfish jars but it will involve a lot of testing in respect to security vulnerabilities and keep track of them as well (earlier that was not the case as Java would do that for us) and this will be an overhead for us.

Looking for some other possible workarounds/ suggestions.

Comment: The 3rd party glassfish JAR workaround you are talking about is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871720.  I don't think there is any other solution.

Comment: The current version of Lotus Domino is HCL Domino 12, and that still uses Java 1.8 ([reference](https://support.hcltechsw.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b068b5bc878ff4105440c9d8cebb35d8)) ... which includes those CORBA classes.  So, it looks like you need to bite the bullet and do one of the following: 1) use Java 8, 2) use the Glassfish workarounds (or similar if they exist) and deal with the issue of tracking vulnerabilities, or 3) abandon Lotus Domino.

Comment: I guess you could also reach out to HCL Support to ask if a new version of Domino for Java 11 is in development, etc.